# npm will not respond at all

Tags: node.js, npm

no matter what npm package I have, or try and install I keep getting this weird syntax error.

```
Users/BenNolan/.node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:66
module.exports = async process => {
                       ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/BenNolan/.node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
```

I have tried updating nvm, npm and node no matter what I try I am still getting the syntax error halfway through the install.

Comment: Using a really old version of Node?